# Can't Make "Owners Group" the owners of any permission group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, online

I am trying to create my **Site Owners** group as the owners of every group on a SPO site under "Group Settings."  When I enter the name of the group in the people picker field, it keeps coming up as "No results found."  I've gone to the People & Groups and can see this group has been created.  Why does it not appear and how do I get around this?  I don't want to have one singular person responsible for permission group management for an entire site.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do other groups show up in the picker, like e.g the members group?

Comment: Hi Rune, yes they do which is why I am even more puzzled lol.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not supported to add SharePoint groups to other SharePoint groups.

You can grant permission to SharePoint group directly.

Or you can create security group from microsoft 365 admin center and add it to SharePoint group.

Comment: Hi Lisa, thanks. I think you misinterpreted the question. I’m not trying to add a group to another group. I’d like to make the Owners group the group owner of all groups. The Owners group is the only group not visible in the people picker on the group settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the Owners group is not visible in the people picker.

From [official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group-permissions), "the Office 365 Group owners is added as hidden principal to the site's owners group and site collection administrators".